# I Can Only Delete Files Permanently, and Cannot Send to Them to Trash in Secondary Drives

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, nautilus, trash

When I am in another drive, I only have the option to delete files permanently, and cannot send files to trash. If I log in as a root user, however, I am able to send files to trash.

The drive has a `.Trash-1000` folder, with `root` as the owner, and permissions `drwxrwxrwx`, so other users should have access to it but they can't.

- **OS:** Arch Linux
- **Kernel:** 5.12.8-arch-1
- **DE:** Gnome 40.1
- **File Viewer:** Nautilus 40.1
- **Drive Type:** NTFS

**EDIT:** Could it be because the drive is NTFS, it doesn't support sending files to the trash?

Comment: There is no shared trash folder. Each user has their own .Trash-nnnn directories (one on each mount-point that isn't where their $HOME is.  The $HOME trash dir is `~/.local/share/Trash`), where 'nnnn' is their UID. It should be owned and RWX by the user.   Also, NTFS doesn't support unix ownership or permissions.  See, e.g., [What is the “.Trash-1000” folder and how to delete it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282332/what-is-the-trash-1000-folder-and-how-to-delete-it).

Comment: BTW, the trash directories are only used by gnome and file browsers that support the gnome gvfs / gio trash standard.  It is not used at all by command line tools like `rm`, although there are command line tools that do use it (the old & deprecated `gvfs-trash` and its replacement `gio trash`, for example).

Comment: ntfs-3g provides user mapping options to have ownership working (else => OP's problem). Here's a tutorial: https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/ntfsusermap.html . Here's the original doc from Tuxera using the Wayback machine, but for some reason it's not available anymore: https://web.archive.org/web/20200321035617/https://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/